# New-PSDrive --Persist doesn't work

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm using powershell to map some network drives on a few computers. It's been working fine mostly, but now it's failing on a computer I haven't tried it on before.

I'm doing

```
 New-PSDrive -Persist -Name $name -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $path -Scope Global
```

And it succeeds. But I can only access the mapped drive in powershell... I can't find it in explorer, and I can't find it in cmd.exe. Doing `net use` in powershell shows them to be OK, doing `net use` in cmd.exe shows them to be unavailable.

This works fine on other computers though!

All computers are running Win 7, and they have the same version of powershell, 3.0. The computer that isn't working might be missing some windows updates that are present on the ones that are working. I can't connect them to the internet to install updates, and have to manually install them via burned cds...

Comment: Is your PowerShell session running with the same user credentials as the user logged into Windows?

Comment: I'm running the powershell session with administrator rights, could that be the problem? The user logged in also has administrator rights. The user logged in to the working computer might also be called 'administrator', I'll look it up. The user logged in to the non-working computer is called something else.

Comment: Have you checked the PowerShell version on that computer? Is it older by any chance?

Comment: Having to use admin credentials to map a drive for a user session doesn't make sense. Any user has rights to map a drive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mapped drives are per user.

If your PowerShell session is running as a different user than the user logged into Windows, then any drives you map in the PowerShell session will not show up in Windows Explorer.

You need to map the drives from a PowerShell session running as the same user that is logged into Windows.

Comment: This solved the problem! When I ran the script without administrator rights the drive showed up. Unfortunately the admin rights was needed for another part of the script, but that's another problem.. :P Thanks!

Comment: BUT where is the -persis???

Comment: Not quite true, because in my case I'm running the shell under the same `User` (username) but with different rights (one w. admin), then the share is not visible.

Comment: UAC prevents elevated applications from having access to mapped drives by default. You can turn that off with a registry change, but it is not recommended. If the elevated account needs the mapped drive, it should be mapped under the elevated account.